# Select radio button behind a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble selecting a particular radio button (Male or female) I have looked at several other posts to no avail. I get the error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group gender-input form-field customize" data-toggle="buttons" title="Gender">
    <label for="census_primary_genderMALE" class="btn btn-input "><input type="radio" value="MALE" name="census.primary.gender" id="census_primary_genderMALE"><div class="radio-switcher"></div>Male</label>

    <label for="census_primary_genderFEMALE" class="btn btn-input active"><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="FEMALE" name="census.primary.gender" id="census_primary_genderFEMALE"><div class="radio-switcher"></div>Female</label>
</div>
```

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbA0M.png)

Comment: Please post an actual code in text and not as an image.

Comment: Your code trial please.

Answer (score 0):

- To click on **`MALE`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='census_primary_genderMALE']")).click();
  ```
- To click on **`FEMALE`**:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='census_primary_genderFEMALE']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can used any of these xpaths

For male

```
//input[@id='census_primary_genderMALE' and @value='MALE']
//input[@type='radio' and @value='MALE']
```

Code like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='MALE']")).click();
```

For Female

```
//input[@id='census_primary_genderFEMALE' and @value='FEMALE']
//input[@type='radio' and @value='FEMALE']
```

Code like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='FEMALE']")).click();
```

You can also used id as locator to select male and female checkbox as they are unique

For Female

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("census_primary_genderFEMALE)).click();
```

For male

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("census_primary_genderMALE)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code with xpath locators:

- To click on MALE :    `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='census_primary_genderMALE']").click()`
- To click on FEMALE:   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='census_primary_genderFEMALE']").click()`